# Spinner - show hint when adapter is empty

Tags: android, android-spinner

I know there have been several questions that dealt with the problem how to add the "Select one..." hint for the `Spinner` before the first selection is made. But that's not my case.

What I need is to display the hint **only** when the `SpinnerAdapter` is empty. By default in such case, nothing happens on click (but that is not the major problem), and most of all, the spinner doesn't display any text, so it looks like this, which obviously doesn't feel right:

[image]

Any idea how to simply handle this problem? I've come up with 2 possible solutions, but I don't like any of them very much:

- If the `SpinnerAdapter` is empty, hide the `Spinner` from the layout and display a `TextView` with the same background as the Spinner instead.
- Implement a custom `SpinnerAdapter` whose `getCount()` returns `1` instead of `0` if the internal list is empty, and at the same time, have its `getView()` return a `TextView` with the required "Empty" message, possibly grey-coloured. But that would require specific checking if the selected item is not the "Empty" one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this `SpinnerWithHintAdapter` class below

```
class SpinnerWithHintAdapter(context: Context, resource: Int = android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item) :
    ArrayAdapter<Any>(context, resource) {

    override fun isEnabled(position: Int): Boolean {
        return position != 0
    }

    override fun getDropDownView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        return (super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent) as TextView).apply {
            if (position == 0) {
                // Set the hint text color gray
                setTextColor(Color.GRAY)
            } else {
                setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
            }
        }
    }

    fun attachTo(spinner: Spinner, itemSelectedCallback: ((Any?) -> Unit)? = null) {
        spinner.apply {
            adapter = this@SpinnerWithHintAdapter
            itemSelectedCallback?.let {
                onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}

                    override fun onItemSelected(
                        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
                        view: View?,
                        position: Int,
                        id: Long
                    ) {
                        val selectedItem = parent?.getItemAtPosition(position)
                        // If user change the default selection
                        // First item is disable and it is used for hint
                        if (position > 0) {
                            it(selectedItem)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to use? Let's assume I have data class called `City`

```
data class City(
    val id: Int,
    val cityName: String,
    val provinceId: Int
) {
    /**
     * By overriding toString function, you will show the dropdown text correctly
     */
    override fun toString(): String {
        return cityName
    }
}
```

In the activity, initiate the adapter, add hint(first item), add main items, and finally attach it to your spinner.

```
SpinnerWithHintAdapter(this@MyActivity)
    .apply {
        // add hint
        add("City")

        // add your main items
        for (city in cityList) add(city)

        // attach this adapter to your spinner
        attachTo(yourSpinner) { selectedItem -> // optional item selected listener
            selectedItem?.apply {
                if (selectedItem is City) {
                    // do what you want with the selected item
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whether your main items is empty or not empty, the hint will show as the first item. But if you want to show the hint only if your main items is empty, you can create if-else conditions. Use the adapter only if your main items is empty, then use standard adapter  (ArrayAdapter, SpinnerAdapter, etc) if your main items is not empty.